# Exporting DNS zonefile from Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I would like to export a DNS zonefile from my Amazon Route 53 setup. Is this possible, or can zonefiles only be created manually? (e.g. through http://www.zonefile.org/?lang=en)

Comment: Already answered here http://serverfault.com/questions/535631/how-to-export-a-hosted-zone-in-aws-route-53

Comment: For YAML AWS CLI output it could be:
  zone["ResourceRecordSets"].collect { |r| "#{r["Name"]} #{r["TTL"]}s #{r["Type"]} #{r["ResourceRecords"].first["Value"]}" }.each { |ri| puts ri }

**It's not accurate for multi-dest records like MX usually and do have SOA and NS, what is garbage**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not possible yet. You'll have to use the API's `ListResourceRecordSets` and build the zonefile yourself.

Comment: See this tool: [https://github.com/barnybug/cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53)    It's a Command line script to administer the Amazon Route 53 dns service. Hope that helps

Comment: *grrrr* I can't believe the developers thought of an "Import" button and forgot "Export!"

Comment: Makes sense that they want to bring in business, but want to make it hard to take away business. But yes very annoying! Thanks for the reference to the cli tool.

Comment: They have record values that aren't RFC compliant. They wouldn't have the ability to export without loss of data.

Comment: Good luck with that! It's simple to get the all the records with that API call into a JSON file. Unfortunately, you then have to edit that file, including editing EVERY SINGLE RECORD in that file so that it has the right format and you can then use it to import. In my case, we have 250+ records, which makes this totally unpractical. Absolute rubbish from AWS!

Answer (score 105):

The following script exports **some** zone details in bind format from Route53. Pass over the domain name as a parameter to script. (This required [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to be installed and configured.)

```
#!/bin/bash

zonename=$1
hostedzoneid=$(aws route53 list-hosted-zones --output json | jq -r ".HostedZones[] | select(.Name == \"$zonename.\") | .Id" | cut -d'/' -f3)
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hostedzoneid --output json | jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"'
```

It should be noted that records that are defined in AWS as pointing to another service will not be exported. You may want to switch to a CNAME for load balancers because their IP addresses can change.

Comment: Please add some explanations as well.

Comment: @szentmarjay-tibor
You can change the following line, since it will give error if the default 
output is different from json.

`hostedzoneid=$(aws route53 list-hosted-zones | jq -r ".HostedZones[] | select(.Name == \"$zonename.\") | .Id" | cut -d'/' -f3) `
"'

Comment: to avoid the null iteration: aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hostedzoneid --output json | jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"'

Comment: The above comment is useful but doesn't escape `(`. Instead use: `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hostedzoneid --output json | jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"'`

Comment: how do I run this text? (sorry if this question might seem strange to someone  )

Comment: @adirabargil Create a shell file and copy this text. Save the file and give executable permissions to file using `chmod +x filename.sh`. Execute this file by running the command `./filename.sh yourdomaintoexport.com`

Comment: for some reason this script does not output all of the zone records for me omitting several latest ones

Comment: Anyone have a windows command prompt version?

Comment: Note that for records with the same name (for example an A and a TXT) only one will be exported.

Comment: @TeddyHiggins just install Windows Subsystem for Linux by Microsoft. Then you can do all kinds of cool linux stuff on your windows machine.

Comment: This worked great for me, except that there were multiple matched zone IDs for my zonename so I needed to put the final `list-resource-record-sets` into a loop.

Comment: At least for me, this command misses CNAME "A" records. If I instead do this: aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hostedzoneid --output json | jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.AliasTarget?.DNSName)\n"' it will pick up the A records. Can't figure how to do both the AliasTarget as well as the ResourceRecords in one command though...

Comment: @MarkWatkins your comment doesn't work for me (MacOS, Bash, JQ 1.7), it just prints `(.Name)  (.TTL)  (.Type)  (.AliasTarget?.DNSName)` several times.

Comment: @mjaggard it doesn't work any more for me either :) I guess JQ changed since a year ago. The key is this: 'aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id HOSTIDZONE --output json'  which does still work (assuming you set the HOSTIDZONE correctly. then fool with jq til it does what you need....

Answer (score 19):

As stated in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337749/exporting-dns-zonefile-from-amazon-route-53/58358563#comment32695864_20461370), the [cli53](https://github.com/barnybug/cli53) is a great tool to interact with Route 53 using the command line interface.

First, configure your account keys in `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AK.....ZP
aws_secret_access_key = 8j.....M0
```

Then, use the `export` command:

```
$ cli53 export --full --debug example.com > example.com.zone 2> example.com.zone.log
```

Verify the `example.com.zone` file after export to make sure that everything is exported correctly.

You can import the zone lately:

```
$ cli53 import --file ./example.com.zone example.com
```

And if you want to transfer the Route53 zone from one AWS account to another, you can use the `profile` option. Just add two named accounts to the `~/.aws/config` file and reference them with the `profile` property during export and import. You can even pipe these two commands.

Comment: This one works better for windows users without the linux subsystem, just check that your AWS cli user/key is allowed to "GetHostedZone".

Answer (score 14):

You can export a JSON file:
`aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <zone-id-here> --output json > route53-records.json`

Comment: Also, ensure that you pass in the argument `--profile <your-aws-profile>` at the end of the command to select the profile that the command will run under. This will help you avoid errors like this `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListResourceRecordSets operation: User: arn:aws:iam::57xxxxxx895:user/devops is not authorized to access this resource`

Comment: Nice and easy, and doesn't require any other CLI tools for a basic export.

Answer (score 8):

You can export with aws api

aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id YOUR_ZONE_ID

Answer (score 6):

Based on @szentmarjay's answer above, except it shows usage and supports zone_id or zone_name. This is my fave because it's standard old school `bind` format, so other tools can do stuff with it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# r53_export

usage() {
  local cmd=$(basename "$0")
  echo -e >&2 "\nUsage: $cmd {--id ZONE_ID|--domain ZONE_NAME}\n"
  exit 1
}

while [[ $1 ]]; do
  if   [[ $1 == --id ]];     then shift; zone_id="$1"
  elif [[ $1 == --domain ]]; then shift; zone_name="$1"
  else usage
  fi
  shift
done

if [[ $zone_name ]]; then
  zone_id=$(
    aws route53 list-hosted-zones --output json \
      | jq -r ".HostedZones[] | select(.Name == \"$zone_name.\") | .Id" \
      | head -n1 \
      | cut -d/ -f3
  )
  echo >&2 "+ Found zone id: '$zone_id'"
fi
[[ $zone_id ]] || usage

aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $zone_id --output json \
  | jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This script allowed me to export and then import the aws zone from one account to another. AWS solution with json export that should be transformed for each of existing in json file records is not acceptable

Answer (score 1):

I updated the more close answer from @szentmarjay-tibor and @jacopkane.
Thanks to them for working solution

With the following one you should get a right output which you'll be able to write to a file. You will still need jq and configured and authorized aws-cli

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Write a domain name after the script path. Example:"
    echo "      ./script.sh example.com"
    exit 0
fi

hostedzoneid=$(aws route53 list-hosted-zones --output json | jq -r ".HostedZones[] | select(.Name == \"$1.\") | .Id" | cut -d'/' -f3)

aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hostedzoneid | \
    jq -jr '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.TTL) \tIN \t\(.Type) \t\(.ResourceRecords[]?.Value)\n"' | \
    sed "s|^$1. |@ |g; s|.$1.||g; s|172800|3600|g" | \
    sed 's|\\052|*|g'
```